# RackSpace CreateImage API using curl is not working

Tags: cloud, rackspace-cloud, rackspace

Whenever i m trying to create image from the given api using curl -:

> curl -i -X POST https://lon.servers.api.rackspacecloud.com/v1.1/xxxxxxxxx/servers/xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx/createImage -H "X-Auth-Token:
>   xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx" -d '{"createImage" : {"name"
>   : "test_image"}}' -H "Content-type: application/json"

It throws me error -:

> {"itemNotFound":{"message":"An unexpected fault
>   occurred.","details":"javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException","code":404}}*
>   Closing connection #0

I need help in this,how to create a server image using curl. But all other rackspace server api's are working fine for me.

I trie same api with version 1.0, 1.1 and 2.0 but ni success.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered over at ServerFault (https://serverfault.com/questions/495087/rackspace-createimage-api-using-curl-is-not-working).

In summary, you will need to change the URL that you are POSTing to to have /action after the UUID, as opposed to /createImage. An example cURL command can be structured as follows:

```
curl -X POST -H "X-Auth-Token: AUTH-TOKEN" -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"createImage" : {"name" : "test"}}' https://lon.servers.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2/ACCOUNT-ID/servers/SERVER-UUID/action
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dave Kuldt. Correct api call is -:

> curl -X POST -H "X-Auth-Token: AUTH-TOKEN" -H "Content-type:
>   application/json" -d '{"createImage" : {"name" : "test"}}'
>   https://lon.servers.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2/ACCOUNT-ID/servers/SERVER-UUID/action